# /etc/passwd shows user in a group, but /etc/group does not

Tags: linux, groups, passwd

I want to verify that the user account *filesender_1* is a member of the group *valid_senders*.

When I look at /etc/group, *filesender_1* is not there:

```
valid_senders:x:12345:production_1
```

I read this as "production_1 is the only member of the group valid_senders, whose group id is 12345."

However:

When I look at /etc/passwd, the group id for *valid_senders* is listed for *filesender_1* ...

```
filesender_1:x:1515:12345:filesender_1:/local/home/filesender_1:/bin/sh
```

... so I know *valid_senders* is the primary group for *filesender_1*.

Is this a surprising discrepancy, or is it normal for /etc/group to list only members where the group is secondary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this discrepancy is normal. I've seen it so many times I stopped looking at the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files and instead started looking at group memberships the way they should be looked at: `getent group <groupname>` and `groups <username>`.

Comment: This doesn't show the right result...@isd's answer is better!

Comment: This is _not_ a solution to the problem... it in fact demonstrates the discrepancy.  getent group <groupname> does not list users whose _primary_ group is groupname, only those who've been added to groupname as a supplementary group.

Comment: As other's have noted, your answer does not solve the issue as (at least for CentOS 8.2) the 'getent group <primary_group>' command does not show the user as a member.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, there is a difference between the primary and supplementary groups.  The primary group is the main one shown in `/etc/passwd`, that a user is in upon login.  For a user to be in a supplementary group, their user name is added to the group entry in `/etc/group`.  If you use `id -a <user>`, it will show the primary and the supplementary groups.  The supplementary groups give access to resources, but any new files are created with primary group.

You can change a users currently active primary group using the `newgrp` command.

It is not necessary for a user to have the primary group also be a secondary group.  All it will do is reduce the number of secondary groups a user can be part of.  Traditionally a user was limited to 32 secondary groups, but that may have changed in recent years.

`usermod` can set a users primary and supplementary groups in one command.  Using a configuration management tool like puppet can also do that without having to worry about what specific command is necessary on different types of unixes.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a program called *members* you can install on most linux distros that lists the actual members of a group whether it is their primary group or a supplementary group.

Typically, when a user is created without specifying a group with -g or --gid, the default behavior is to set their primary group as their username, and this gid is not placed in the /etc/group file.  Hence files and directories created by the user joe will have ownership joe:joe.  But you will not find group 'joe' in the /etc/group file.

If you add the user joe to group 'students', then running

```
getent group students
```

will show joe in the list of users in group *students*.

Running the program

```
members <groupname>
```

on a group will show users who are members, either primary or supplementary, of *groupname*.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, system administrators should add the user to their primary group's member list in /etc/group because the getpwent() family of system calls will remove duplicates when called.  Programs aren't supposed to read /etc/group or /etc/passwd directly, they are supposed to use the system calls.  All this has been true for at least 20 years now, and probably much longer.

Comment: The two halves of your answer contradict each other.

Comment: Don't know how to say it better, nor what you mean by halves, but I'll try an example.  My primary group is sysman, gid 1200.  So in my /etc/password entry, the gid field contains 1200, and my userid also appears in the list of userids for group sysman in /etc/group.  When any program uses the standard means of asking for my group memberships, everything works.  But remember programs should never read / etc/passed or /etc/group, that dodges the name service switch and is very bad practice.  Use the system calls.

Answer (score -3):

You should use
`lid -g <group>'`

Comment: This needs a better explanation.